# Moodle Single Sign on not working

Tags: office365, moodle

I have registered my Moolde application into Azure AD. Configured Office 365 and OpenID connect in Moolde. Login option is enable in login page of Moodle application. I already logged in to Office 365 account in one of my browser tab. In the same browser i opened that login with Office 365 link, it redirects to office login page and ask for the credentials. But it needs to login internally.

Please give a solution for this.